# get_the_ID() function does not return the post id in init hook function

Tags: wordpress

Please consider the code:

```
function mcqac_wp_enqueue_assets() {

    if (is_admin()) {

        wp_enqueue_script(
            'mcqac-js-admin', // Handle.
            PLUGIN_URL . 'build/main-admin.js',
            array( 'jquery' ), // Dependencies, defined above.
            filemtime( PLUGIN_PATH . 'build/main-admin.js' ), // Version: File modification time.
            true // Enqueue the script in the footer.
        );

        $mcqacAdminData = array();

        if (get_the_ID()) {
            $mcqacAdminData['options'] = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'mcqac_options', true);
        }

        wp_localize_script('mcqac-js-admin', 'mcqacAdminData', $mcqacAdminData);
    }
}

add_action('init', 'mcqac_wp_enqueue_assets');
```

The `get_the_ID()` does not return anything when I am in the edit post page. Seems like `init` action hook is fired before the post query.

What is the solution?

Comment: The `get_the_ID()` works only inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `template_redirect` hook instead of `init`.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'prefix_get_page_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed the `admin_enqueue_scripts` action hook instead of `init` action hook. And also declare `global $post` to get post id from this variable.